# breeze memory management - pattern / practice?

Tags: breeze

I have an old SL4/ria app, which I am looking to replace with breeze.  I have a question about memory use and caching.  My app loads lists of Jobs (a typical user would have access to about 1,000 of these jobs).  Additionally, there are quite a few lookup entity types.  I want to make sure these are cached well client-side, but updated per session.  When a user opens a job, it loads many more related entities (anywhere from 200 - 800 additional entities) which compose multiple matrix-style views for the jobs.  A user can view the list of jobs, or navigate to view 1 job at a time.

I feel that I should be concerned with memory management, especially not knowing how browsers might deal with this.  Originally I felt this should all be 1 EntityManager and I would detachEntities when user navigates away from a job, but I'm thinking this might benefit from multiple managers by intended lifetime.  Or perhaps I should create a new dataservice & EntityManager each time the user navigates to a new hash '/#/' area, since comments on clear() seems to indicate that this would be faster?  If I did this, I suppose I will be using pub/sub to notify other viewmodels of changes to entities?  This seems complex and defeating some of the benefits of breeze as the context.

Any tips or thoughts about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I understand the question. I think I would use a multi-manager approach:

1. Lookups Manager - holds once-per session reference (lookup) entities
2. JobsView Manager - "readonly" list of Jobs in support of the JobsView
3. JobEditor Manager - One per edit session.

The Lookups Manager maintains the canonical copy of reference entities. You can fill it once with a single call to server (see docs for how). This Lookups Manager will *Breeze-export* these reference entities to other managers which *Breeze-import* them as they are created. I am assuming that, while numerous and diverse, the total memory footprint of reference entities is pretty low ... low enough that you can afford to have more than one copy in multiple managers. There are more complicated solutions if that is NOT so. But let that be for now.

The JobsView Manager has the necessary reference entities for its display. If you only displayed a projection of the Jobs, it would not have Jobs in cache. You might have an array and key map instead. Let's keep it simple and assume that it has all the Jobs but not their related entities.

You never save changes with this manager! When editing or creating a Job, your app always fires up a "Job Editor" view with its own VM and JobEditor Manager. Again, you import the reference entities you need and, when editing an existing Job, you import the Job too.

I would take this approach anyway ... not just because of memory concerns. I like isolating my edit sessions into sandboxes. Eases cancellation. Gives me a clean way to store pending changes in browser storage so that the user won't lose his/her work if the app/browser goes down. Opens the door to editing several Jobs at the same time ... without worrying about mutually dependent entities-with-changes. It's a proven pattern that we've used forever in SL apps and should apply as well in JS apps.

When a Job edit succeeds, You have to tell the local client world about it. Lots of ways to do that. If the ONLY place that needs to know is the JobsView, you can hardcode a backchannel into the app. If you want to be more clever, you can have a central singleton service that raises events specifically about Job saving. The JobsView and each new JobEditor communicate with this service. And if you want to be hip, you use an in-process "Event Aggregator" (your pub/sub) for this purpose. I'd probably be using [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) for this app anyway and it has an event aggregator in the box.

Honestly, it's not that complicated to use and importing/exporting entities among managers is a ... ahem ... breeze. Well worth it compared to refreshing the Jobs List every time you return to it (although you'll want a "refresh button" too because OTHER users could be adding/changing those Jobs). You retain plenty of Breeze benefits: querying, validation, change-tracking, batch saves, entity navigation (those reference lists work "for free" in Breeze).

As a refinement, I don't know that I would automatically destroy the JobEditor view/viewmodel/manager when I returned to the JobsView. In my experience, people often return to the same Job that they just left. I might hold on to a view so you could go back and forth quickly. But now I'm getting tricky.

Comment: This is a great response.  Thanks for all the description.  I guess I had not really thought about edit-lifecycle just yet.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Ward, thanks for this. I have a question: in a AMD environment such as Durandal wouldn't it be possible to require(lookupManager) rather than breeze-export/import it? Is that going to cause me trouble down the line?

Comment: It's certainly possible. Not sure what it buys you. With all perf matters it is crucial to first measure and understand what specifically is the problem and only then get creative with solutions. It's easy to go after data but the actual problem could be somewhere else (DOM writing, excessive eventing/watching, unreleased objects, GC-thrashing)